# Having an error when trying to run my Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I´m trying to make a python GUI with Tkinter that reads an excel and then upload the excel information into a db. When trying to run the script, I´m able to upload the excel spreadsheet and read it but when I click the "submit" button. I get the "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context." error. Does someone know how this works? Because I know how this works on Flask but not on Tkinter.

Code:

```
root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("500x500") 
#root.pack_propagate(True)
#root.resizable(0, 0) 



Label(root, text="Metadata Automation", font=16).place(rely=0, relx=0.10)


frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Excel Data")
frame1.place(height=250, width=500)


file_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Open File")
file_frame.place(height=100, width=400, rely=0.55, relx=0)


button1 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Browse A File", command=lambda: File_dialog())
button1.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.50)

button2 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Load File", command=lambda: Load_excel_data())
button2.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.30)


label_file = ttk.Label(file_frame, text="No File Selected")
label_file.place(rely=0, relx=0)



tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1) # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).

treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview) # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview) # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set) # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x") # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y") # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget


survey = tk.IntVar()
project = tk.IntVar()

#Add checkboxes
SurveyCheckbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Insert a survey", variable=survey, onvalue=1, offvalue=3)
ProjectCheckbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Insert a project", variable=project, onvalue=2, offvalue=4)

SurveyCheckbox.deselect()
ProjectCheckbox.deselect()

#place checkboxes under the excel reader
SurveyCheckbox.place(rely=0.80, relx=0)
ProjectCheckbox.place(rely=0.85, relx=0)


#Add Button
Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: Gui(), fg="red").place(rely=0.90, relx=0.1)



def File_dialog():

    #This Function will open the file explorer and assign the chosen file path to label_file
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                          title="Select A File",
                                          filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),("All Files", "*.*")))
    
    label_file["text"] = filename
    
    return filename
  
def Load_excel_data():

    #If the file selected is valid this will load the file into the Treeview
    file_path = label_file["text"]
    
    try:

        file = r"{}".format(file_path)
        
        if file[-4:] == ".csv":
            
            df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=3, engine='xlrd')
            
            """clear_data()"""

            tv1["column"] = list(df.columns)
            tv1["show"] = "headings"

            for column in tv1["columns"]:
                
                tv1.heading(column, text=column) # let the column heading = column name

            df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist() # turns the dataframe into a list of lists

            for row in df_rows:
                
                tv1.insert("", "end", values=row) # inserts each list into the treeview. For parameters see https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert
            

        else:
            
            df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=3, engine='openpyxl')
                
            """clear_data(tv1)"""

            tv1["column"] = list(df.columns)
            tv1["show"] = "headings"

            for column in tv1["columns"]:
                    
                tv1.heading(column, text=column) # let the column heading = column name

            df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist() # turns the dataframe into a list of lists

            for row in df_rows:
                    
                tv1.insert("", "end", values=row) # inserts each list into the treeview. For parameters see https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert
        
    except ValueError:
        
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
        return None

    except FileNotFoundError:
        
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
        return None
    
    return df

def clear_data():
    
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    return None

def Gui():
    
        survey_chk = survey.get()
        project_chk = project.get()
        
        utils.ConnectionInit()
        df = Load_excel_data()
        message = ' '

        connection = utils.CreateConnection()

        if survey_chk == 1 and project_chk != 2:
            utils.CreateSurvey(connection, df)
            message = 'hi'
            
        
        elif project_chk == 2 and survey_chk != 1:
            #utils.CreateProject(connection, df)
            message = 'chau'
        
        elif survey_chk == 1 and project_chk == 2:
            #utils.CreateSurvey(connection, df)
            #utils.CreateProject(connection, df)
            message = 'hola'

        lblMessage.config(text=message)


lblMessage = tk.Label(root)
lblMessage.place(rely=0.90, relx=0.10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SCDBOHU\.conda\envs\Proyecto\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/SCDBOHU/Desktop/GitRepos/SeismicDataAutomation/Project/GUI_TEST.PY", line 68, in <lambda>
    Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: Gui(), fg="red").place(rely=0.90, relx=0.1)
  File "c:/Users/SCDBOHU/Desktop/GitRepos/SeismicDataAutomation/Project/GUI_TEST.PY", line 159, in Gui
    utils.CreateSurvey(connection, df)
  File "c:\Users\SCDBOHU\Desktop\GitRepos\SeismicDataAutomation\Project\utils.py", line 133, in CreateSurvey
    SurveyProjnSelection(connection,crs,tfm,projn_id,survey_list,flag_2d)
  File "c:\Users\SCDBOHU\Desktop\GitRepos\SeismicDataAutomation\Project\utils.py", line 168, in SurveyProjnSelection
    flash(f"The Geoframe map projection ID {projn_id} you were trying to create with your survey is already created.", 'warning')
  File "C:\Users\SCDBOHU\.conda\envs\Proyecto\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 421, in flash
    flashes = session.get("_flashes", [])
  File "C:\Users\SCDBOHU\.conda\envs\Proyecto\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Users\SCDBOHU\.conda\envs\Proyecto\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\SCDBOHU\.conda\envs\Proyecto\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Comment: Look at the error traceback. The error comes from somewhere inside the `Project\utils.py` file that you created. It doesn't look like the problem is with `tkinter`.

Comment: You can’t run tkinter from a web server, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TheLizzard you are right, was my bad, I was coding something wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: @BryanOakley was not that what I was trying to do. Thanks tho for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try running without anaconda environment because I run without anaconda environment
my file is running

[image: My computer]

But the code is same

code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("500x500") 
root.pack_propagate(True)
root.resizable(0, 0) 



Label(root, text="Metadata Automation", font=16).place(rely=0, relx=0.10)


frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Excel Data")
frame1.place(height=250, width=500)


file_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Open File")
file_frame.place(height=100, width=400, rely=0.55, relx=0)


button1 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Browse A File", command=lambda: File_dialog())
button1.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.50)

button2 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Load File", command=lambda: Load_excel_data())
button2.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.30)


label_file = ttk.Label(file_frame, text="No File Selected")
label_file.place(rely=0, relx=0)



tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1) # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).

treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview) # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview) # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set) # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x") # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y") # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget


survey = tk.IntVar()
project = tk.IntVar()

#Add checkboxes
SurveyCheckbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Insert a survey", variable=survey, onvalue=1, offvalue=3)
ProjectCheckbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Insert a project", variable=project, onvalue=2, offvalue=4)

SurveyCheckbox.deselect()
ProjectCheckbox.deselect()

#place checkboxes under the excel reader
SurveyCheckbox.place(rely=0.80, relx=0)
ProjectCheckbox.place(rely=0.85, relx=0)


#Add Button
Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: Gui(), fg="red").place(rely=0.90, relx=0.1)



def File_dialog():

    #This Function will open the file explorer and assign the chosen file path to label_file
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                          title="Select A File",
                                          filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),("All Files", "*.*")))
    
    label_file["text"] = filename
    
    return filename
  
def Load_excel_data():

    #If the file selected is valid this will load the file into the Treeview
    file_path = label_file["text"]
    
    try:

        file = r"{}".format(file_path)
        
        if file[-4:] == ".csv":
            
            df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=3, engine='xlrd')
            
            """clear_data()"""

            tv1["column"] = list(df.columns)
            tv1["show"] = "headings"

            for column in tv1["columns"]:
                
                tv1.heading(column, text=column) # let the column heading = column name

            df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist() # turns the dataframe into a list of lists

            for row in df_rows:
                
                tv1.insert("", "end", values=row) # inserts each list into the treeview. For parameters see https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert
            

        else:
            
            df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=3, engine='openpyxl')
                
            """clear_data(tv1)"""

            tv1["column"] = list(df.columns)
            tv1["show"] = "headings"

            for column in tv1["columns"]:
                    
                tv1.heading(column, text=column) # let the column heading = column name

            df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist() # turns the dataframe into a list of lists

            for row in df_rows:
                    
                tv1.insert("", "end", values=row) # inserts each list into the treeview. For parameters see https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert
        
    except ValueError:
        
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
        return None

    except FileNotFoundError:
        
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
        return None
    
    return df

def clear_data():
    
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    return None

def Gui():
    
        survey_chk = survey.get()
        project_chk = project.get()
        
        utils.ConnectionInit()
        df = Load_excel_data()
        message = ' '

        connection = utils.CreateConnection()

        if survey_chk == 1 and project_chk != 2:
            utils.CreateSurvey(connection, df)
            message = 'hi'
            
        
        elif project_chk == 2 and survey_chk != 1:
            #utils.CreateProject(connection, df)
            message = 'chau'
        
        elif survey_chk == 1 and project_chk == 2:
            #utils.CreateSurvey(connection, df)
            #utils.CreateProject(connection, df)
            message = 'hola'

        lblMessage.config(text=message)


lblMessage = tk.Label(root)
lblMessage.place(rely=0.90, relx=0.10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```